# Is it possible to include a folder of javascripts files instead of adding them one by one?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to include a folder of javascripts files instead of adding them one by one?

Something like this:

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
     src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/?.js></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
 src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")  %>'></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
 src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min.js")  %>'></s

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
 src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js")  %>'></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
 src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.simplemodal.js")  %>'></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
 src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js")  %>'></sc

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" 
 src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.noselect.min.js")  %>'></script>
```

Comment: Probably not inbuild, but you should be able to write a helper for this. Just iterate over all the nodes in the folder and inject them into the page.

Answer (score 2):

- For my former project we created a custom **HttpHandler** for this. Read out the content of the folder and injected that. Due to limitations however of having to make the scripts sorted for correct injection, we later improved it by creating a custom section in web.config. These held the correct order of how to inject the scripts.
- Another solution's to minimize the scripts and to have them put into one file. Be sure to also read this article: [Automatically minify and combine JavaScript in Visual Studio](http://encosia.com/2009/05/20/automatically-minify-and-combine-javascript-in-visual-studio/).

Comment: I will recommend mix of both approaches i.e. use a http-handler that would serve the minified and combined java-scripts files.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="scriptsToInclude" runat="server"><ItemTemplate>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/" + Container.DataItem + ".js") %>'></script>
</ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

And in codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(..) {
  scriptsToInclude.DataSource = new [] { "jquery-1.5.1.min", "jquery.localscroll-1.2.7-min", "jquery.simplemodal", ... };
  scriptsToInclude.DataBind();
}
```

Got an idea?

Comment: Yes, I got it. I think I'll user `Directory.GetFiles` insead for DataSource. Thanks.

Comment: @Jack Yes, `Directory.GetFiles` is a good approach, but be careful - there you can have problems with order of js files. If so - order them by some prefix, like 10_jquery.min.js, 20_jquery.localscroll.js, etc..

Comment: @Jack Also `Directory.GetFiles` returns an array with full pathed files. So don't forget to trim it by the website root path

Comment: Actually I haven't faced a problem in the order in js files before. But I'll consider it rightnow.

Answer (score 0):

No because your browser doesn´t know the contents of the folder. If your browser would know the contents it would be very dangerous.

This is only possible with a helper program.

Comment: It's OK to be on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, but it is very easy to compile a folder of .js files into one(possibly minified) file.

In fact, it's so easy, you can automate it and turn it into a part of the build process. Most people do.

One of the best tools for the job is the [Google Closure compiler](http://code.google.com/intl/bg/closure/compiler/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create one main file and
   include all your **JavaScript** files
   to this file.  And then add this one
   file to page

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/). It's a Visual Studio plug-in and great for combining all your Javascript files into one file and then sending it to the server. It'll not only save the hassle of adding each file but also would require only one HTTP request to get all the Javascript. Works for CSS too :)